# Python - plt.savefig in a nested for loop

Tags: python, plot, subplot

I would like to create a pdf containing 12 figures/subplot processed in a nested 'for' loop.

The 12 figures are produced from 4 metrics applied to 3 different variables (3*4=12).

Here is the code that I am using:

```
#########VARIABLES#############################
df = pd.read_csv('scores.csv',delimiter=',')
sta='Jony'
cvars=['Qle','Qh','NEE']
exps=['ctr','lai']
expsC={'ctr':'k','lai':'b'}
stats=['MBE','SD','NME','pcorr']

##################FUNCTION#########################
def extract_score(df,station,cvar,exp,score):
    a=df[(df.station == station) & (df.cvar == cvar) & 
          (df.exp == exp) ]
    return a[score].values[0]
def extract_score_exp(df,station,cvar,score,expS=None):
    out=[]
    if expS is None:
        exps=np.unique(df.exp)
    else:
        expsf=np.unique(df.exp)
        exps=[]
        for ee in expsf:
            if expS in ee:
                exps.append(ee)
    for exp in exps:
        out.append(extract_score(df,station,cvar,exp,score))
    return exps,out

def get_val_exp(exps,pos=1):
    return [float(bb.split('_')[pos]) for bb in exps]

#####################PLOT###################################
for j,cvar in enumerate(cvars):
    fig=plt.figure()
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3,1), (j,0))
    for i,stat in enumerate(stats):
        ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((1,4), (0,i))
        for exp in exps:
            xscore0=extract_score(df,sta,cvar,exp,stat)
            xx0=250
            expsP,xscore=extract_score_exp(df,sta,cvar,stat,expS='_'+exp)
            xx=get_val_exp(expsP)
            ax2.plot(xx,xscore,'.',c=expsC[exp])
            ax2.plot(xx0,xscore0,'x',c=expsC[exp])
        ax.set_title(stat,fontsize=8)
    plt.show()
    plt.savefig('/home/david/test_pals/result/output/test.pdf')

    plt.close()
```

The code runs fine and the ´plt.show()´ command actually shows what I want, as seen on the following picture:

[image]

But unfortunately, the ´plt.savefig´ command just save the last 1*4 subplot produced:

[image]

I tried different place in the loop for the ´plt.savefig´ but I did not succeed to save the 4*3 figures in one pdf. Does anyone has indication why?

Comment: If you look at the picture that's showing up via the savefig command, it looks like it corresponds to the third or last row of four pictures given by show. This suggests you might be saving over the other two rows when you iterate?

Comment: @RichardKYu: that's exactly the case! But I can't figure out with this nested loop how to not overwrite the produced figures

Comment: My guess is that ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((1,4), (0,i)) should be ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((1,4), (j,i))

Since you are setting the graph as (0,i) each time it is not incrementing down as you would like, i.e. (0,i), (1,i), (2,i).

Comment: @RichardKYu - It now produces a blank file

Comment: Is the plt.show() also blank?

Comment: @RichardKYu - the plt.show is not blank and once again it shows the desired output that I wish to save :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193103/discussion-between-richard-k-yu-and-steve).